# Configuring endpoints for a web service with multiple interfaces

Tags: c#, web-services, interface, web-config

I need to be able to configure an endpoint for each interface that I have in a web service that I created.
Using a test web form application, I can successfully use either interface. But when I try to add a second endpoint with the second interface, I get the error below:

[image: Error when updating service reference]
Here are the web.config file for the web service:

```
    <basicHttpBinding>
      <binding name="myBindingConfiguration1" closeTimeout="00:01:00" />
    </basicHttpBinding>
  </bindings>

    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="PaymentServiceBehavior" name="PaymentService.PaymentService">
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="myBindingConfiguration1"
          name="PaymentInsecureService" contract="PaymentService.IPaymentService" />
        <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="myBindingConfiguration1"
          name="PaymentSecureService" contract="PaymentService.IPaymentSecureService" />
      </service>
    </services>
```

This is the web.config file from the test application:

```
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IPaymentService" />
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<client>
  <endpoint address="http://localhost:4567/Payment.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding"
    bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IPaymentService" contract="PaymentService.IPaymentService"
    name="PaymentInsecureService" />
  <endpoint address="http://localhost:4567/Payment.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding"
    bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IPaymentService" contract="PaymentService.IPaymentSecureService"
    name="PaymentSecureService" />
</client>
```

This is the code for the web service interfaces:

```
namespace PaymentService
{
    [ServiceContract (Namespace = "name of namespace here")]
    public interface IPaymentSecureService
    {
        //Initiate a credit card authorization.
        [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
        void Authorize(...12 parameters here...);

        more methods here....
    }
}

namespace PaymentService
{
    [ServiceContract (Namespace = "name of namespace here")]
    public interface IPaymentService
    {
        //Initiate a credit card authorization.
        [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
        void Authorize(...13 parameters here....);

        more methods here...
    }
}
```

Is it possible to have an endpoint for each interface when one of the interface methods has the same name but a different method signature?

Is there something wrong with my config files?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried enabling httpGet on the meta endpoint?

Comment: This is in the web service file.     <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="PaymentServiceBehavior">
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have posted this problem on 2 other forums. Although you should be able to have 2 interfaces with the same method name but different signatures and use 2 endpoints to access each of the interfaces, I do not believe it is possible UNLESS you do one of the following:

1. The namespace for each interface is unique.
2. The name attribute for the overloaded method is unique.

I choose the first option because I am updating legacy code and adding the name attribute to the method essentially changes the name of the method.  So all of the client applications that use this method in the service will need to be changed.  I wanted to minimize the changes to these applications so I went with changing the namespace.

I thought that this namespace attribute is used to point to a location where the service resides.  According to the Microsoft documentation and my limited local testing, this is not the case.  This is an excerpt of the documentation:

Identify your XML Web service with a namespace that you control. For example, you can use the Internet domain name of your company as part of the namespace. Many XML Web service namespaces look similar to URLs, however, namespaces do not have to point to actual resources on the Web. (XML Web service namespaces are URIs.) (Uniform Resource Identifier). By using XML namespaces you can uniquely identify elements or attributes in a xml document. The service description for a xml web service is in xml, specifically in WSDL.

I hope this can help someone else with this problem...